# SmartGwt get VLayout height after add members

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have problem a with getting `VLayout` height after I add a member to it

```
VLayot layout = new VLayout();
```

in presenter I have code

```
display.getAnswerPanel().removeMembers(display.getAnswerPanel().getMembers());
```

which clear all members, and I add another (I have buttons, when I clik them, it clears all `VLayout` and adds new members)

```
layout.addMember(new Button("Example"));
```

I need to get `offsetHeight` of this `VLayout` on start and everytime I click the button, my problem is that in first time when I load the page, my `offsetHeigh is 1px, each next time when I click button is ok, it shows me the correct value. Can someone help me?

I tried to use this code

```
scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
    layout.getOffsetHeight();
}
```

but the situation is the same, First time I don't have the correct value.

Comment: Make sure that your layout has been drawn before you try to assess its dimensions.

Comment: How can I make sure that layout is drawn ?

Comment: Make sure that you call layout.show() before you try to get its height /width.

Comment: I called layout.show(), but it's doesen't effect. When I refresh browser, sometimes I have good height sometimes not. I do not know what it depends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartGWT getOffsetHeight after layout is drawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380558/smartgwt-getoffsetheight-after-layout-is-drawn)

Comment: resolved in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380558/smartgwt-getoffsetheight-after-layout-is-drawn

Answer (score 0):

we can get the height and width of any widget only after the widget is being loaded or on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler#scheduleDeferred() executes at the end of the GWT loop, so there's still no time for the layout to update either. I guess there's not much you can do besides using the traditional timer hack (in case any reader is in doubt, yes, I meant using setTimeout() or Scheduler.get().scheduleWithFixedDelay(cmd, 200) ).