# SmartGWT getOffsetHeight after layout is drawn

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I need get offsetHeight of Vlayout, but until i know that it's drawn. How I can check that, this component is drawn ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartGwt get VLayout height after add members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318080/smartgwt-get-vlayout-height-after-add-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can check that, this component is drawn ?

You can override the onDraw method of Canvas and add some custom functionality there.

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw()
  {
    super.onDraw();
    //your code
  }
```

Alternatively you can add a draw handler to the component:

```
 addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onDraw(DrawEvent event)
     {
        //Do stuff
     }
  });
```